# Recursive read div contents and post via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I created a function that reads the content of some divs and puts them into an array. My divs are organized as such:

```
<div class="row clearfix" id="moltiplicandum1">
    <div class="column third">
        <select id="test_set" type="text" style="width:100%">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="set1">set1</option>
            <option value="set2">set2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="column third">
        <select id="avail_cat" type="text" style="width:100%">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="cat1">cat1</option>
            <option value="cat2">cat2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="column third">
        <select id="avail_class" type="text" style="width:100%">
            <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="class1">class1</option>
            <option value="class2">class2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix" id="moltiplicandum#">...</div>
```

From `moltiplicandum1` to an arbitrary `montiplicandum#` (all created via js using a button). So, the function that is going to read the contents of all "select" for each "moltiplicandum" returns an error:

> TypeError: div is null

on the line `var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('select');`. Here the function:

```
var divArray = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById("moltiplicandum"+i);
    var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j += 1) {
        divArray.push($(divs[j]).val());
    }
}
```

If I comment the external `for`, defining `var i = 1`, it works (only for "moltiplicandum1").

Could someone help me to figure out the problem? Thank you1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery why don't you simply use the selector? like this:

```
selectArray = Array.prototype.map.call($(".moltiplicandum select"),(function(el){
 return el.value;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Useful also the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what any of the code you've shown has to do with either recursion or AJAX, however given your goal of building an array of all the values from the `select` elements you can simply use jQuery's `map()` method.

You can also add a common class to the `moltiplicandumN` elements so that you can genericise the logic. Try this:

```js
$('.moltiplicandum select').change(function() {
  var selectArray = $('.moltiplicandum select').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(selectArray)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix moltiplicandum" id="moltiplicandum1">
  <div class="column third">
    <select id="test_set1" type="text" style="width:100%">
      <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="set1">set1</option>
      <option value="set2">set2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="column third">
    <select id="avail_cat1" type="text" style="width:100%">
      <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="cat1">cat1</option>
      <option value="cat2">cat2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="column third">
    <select id="avail_class1" type="text" style="width:100%">
      <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="class1">class1</option>
      <option value="class2">class2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix moltiplicandum" id="moltiplicandum2">
  <div class="column third">
    <select id="test_set2" type="text" style="width:100%">
      <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="set1">set1</option>
      <option value="set2">set2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="column third">
    <select id="avail_cat2" type="text" style="width:100%">
      <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="cat1">cat1</option>
      <option value="cat2">cat2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="column third">
    <select id="avail_class2" type="text" style="width:100%">
      <option selected disabled value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="class1">class1</option>
      <option value="class2">class2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, be careful of duplicating `id` attributes. I added a numerical value to the `id` of the repeated `select` controls in the HTML above.

Comment: Thank you, very useful. I did't noticed the repeated ids. Just for clarification, data I put into the array will be sent to an Watson API via AJAX.